# comparison of string with nil failed

Tags: ruby, string, char

Im trying to write a loop that counts the number of capitals in a word. When I run this code I get an error stating that nil can't be compared to a string. I don't understand this because I am comparing a a string to a string?

```
passwort = gets.chomp
i = 0
capitals = 0
while(i < (passw0ort.length) + 1) do
    if('A' <= passwort[i] && passwort[i] <= 'Z')
        capitals = capitals + 1
    else
        end
    i = i + 1
end
```

Greetings Patrick

Comment: It is invalid in the first place. What is `passw0ort`?

Comment: Use [`String#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-count): `passwort.count("A-Z")`

Comment: For the future, I'd recommend formatting the code and indicating where the error is happening to draw attention. However, I'm guessing that, if you print out `passwort[i]` inside the loop, you'll see the error probably occurs _after_ all the letters are printed. Arrays are counted from `0` to `length - 1`, so `i<(passwort.length)+1` is too long. `passwort[passwort.length]` is always `nil`.

Comment: @Stefan It is `passwort`, not `password`.

Comment: @user2262149 Your edit is invalid. You changed the code. You can change the text, but not the code (other than formatting white spaces or comments). It was good that you fixed the mistakes in the text, and that you formatted the code by adding the four spaces, but you should not have changed its content.

Comment: @sawa My mistake, apologies

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting `nil` is that you are counting more elements than there are.

`i<(passw0ort.length)+1` should be `i<(passw0ort.length)`, because `.length` returns a number bigger than zero, if the string is not empty, while arrays are zero-indexed. The last time the loop runs, you try to access an element *after* the string, which does not exist.

So on your last loop iteration, you are comparing a string to nil, which results in this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `scan` method of `String` class to filter out only capital letters

```
capitals = passwort.scan(/[A-Z]/).count
```

Comment: `chomp` always returns a string

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is too "long":

```
passwort = "test"
i = 0
while i < passwort.length + 1
  puts "passwort[#{i}] == #{passwort[i].inspect}"
  i = i + 1
end
```

Output:

```
passwort[0] == "t"
passwort[1] == "e"
passwort[2] == "s"
passwort[3] == "t"
passwort[4] == nil # <- this is your nil error
```

You can fix this by changing `i < passwort.length + 1` to `i < passwort.length`.

However, instead of using temporary variables and while loops, you can use [`String#chars`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-chars) to get the string's characters as an array and [`Array#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-count) to count the ones satisfying your condition:

```
passwort = "123fooBAR"
passwort.chars.count { |char| 'A' <= char && char <= 'Z' }
#=> 3
```

Or simply [String#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-count):

```
passwort.count("A-Z") #=> 3
```

From the docs:

> The sequence `c1-c2` means all characters between `c1` and `c2`.